# HQL - outer join on 2 conditions

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, criteria, outer-join

I need to write The Query. Here is a simplified problem:
There are named baskets. There are fruits in them (0 or more). Basket have owners (1 or more). Fruits also have owners (1 or more). I want to get a list of Joe's fruits inside Joe's baskets, including Joe's baskets without any Joe's fruits. Here we go:

```
select basket.name, fruit.name from Owner owner
join owner.baskets basket
left outer join basket.fruits fruit WITH OWNER in (FRUIT.OWNERS)
where owner.id = joe_id
```

But... It does not work in HQL. It only looks nice. It is simple in SQL.

So, the question is: 
**how can I do join on more then one condition in HQL or criteria API** 
(using Hibernate 3.3).

I need paging so I cannot fetch empty baskets later because I wont be able to calculate which items should be on which pages. My current solution is a native query, but there must be a way...

Comment: An actual error message from hibernate would be most helpful here...

Comment: I cannot find example stacktrace anywhere, but it said that this query is incorrect because the WITH clause combines conditions of two different branches of the query AST tree, or something along this line. Anyway, WITH clause works if both conditions relate to the same object: `left join cat.kittens as *kitten* with *kitten*.bodyWeight > 10.0` (example from hibernate documentation). Actually, whenever I needed to use WITH, it didn't work ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can solve your problem with criteria API and aliases or sub-criterias.

Hibernate criteria creates aliases with left outer join for fruits and inner for basket.

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Account.class).setProjection(
            Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Property.forName("fruit.name"))
                    .add(Property.forName("basket.name"))
    );
    criteria.createAlias("fruits", "fruit",1);
    criteria.createAlias("baskets","basket",0);
    criteria.add(Property.forName("fruit.owner").eqProperty("basket.owner"));
    List<Object> l = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq( "id", some_joe_id_var ).list();
```

Comment: Well, its equivalent of `SELECT .. JOIN ... LEFT OUTER JOIN basket.fruits fruit WHERE fruit.owner = basket.owner` and it is incorrect. Why? Because it joins all Joe's baskets with all fruits and THEN filters out results with fruits not belonging to Joe. It filters out Joe's green basket with Ann's apples and this green basket should instead appear in the results (as a single row with 'green' basked and NULL fruit)